# PCA as scaled average of original variables

Tags: pca, mean

Let $X_i=(x_{i1},...,x_{ip})$ be a vector of $p$-dimensional $n$ observations. Suppose that we apply *principal component analysis* and find the $p$ principal components. Also, suppose that the $p$ loadings of the first component $u_1$ are all positive and roughly of the same size.

Why can we regard the first component to be an approximate scaled average of the $p$ original variables?

(I suppose this question is related to [Can averaging all the variables be seen as a crude form of PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93905/can-averaging-all-the-variables-be-seen-as-a-crude-form-of-pca), in addition to the answer given to that question I would like to see why the above claim holds in a more formal fashion)