# distance measure of angles between two vectors, taking magnitude into account

Tags: clustering, distance

Suppose I have two vectors, `v1` and `v2`, from which I can calculate the angle between these two vectors as a measure of their "distance", using the arccos function, say. For example:

```
v1 = c(100,200, 500,600)    
v2 = c( 50, 30,  10,5)      
v3 = c( 10,  7,  30,40) 

# pairwise angles
acos( as.numeric((v1 %*% v2) / (norm_vec(v1) * norm_vec(v2))) ) * 180 / pi  # 66.8017
acos( as.numeric((v2 %*% v3) / (norm_vec(v2) * norm_vec(v3))) ) * 180 / pi  # 66.67337
acos( as.numeric((v1 %*% v3) / (norm_vec(v1) * norm_vec(v3))) ) * 180 / pi  # 8.061138
```

This kind of measure will give similar distances (angles) **regardless of the magnitude of the elements in the vectors**. For instance, the distance between `v1` and `v2` is 66.80, and the distance between `v2` and `v3` is similarly 66.67, but clearly the **magnitude** of `v2` and `v3` are more similar than `v1`, so I am thinking of a measure that will also take the "magnitude" into account when calculating the dissimilarity. In other words, dist(v1, v2) should be greater than dist(v2,v3), but this result is obtained by **still using the pairwise angle idea**. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thank you all for your replies! For the equivalence of Euclidean and angle distances, I use the same vectors as above to calculate the Euclidean distances:

```
# Euclidean distance
ed <- function(x1,x2)
  sqrt(sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2))
ed(v1,v2)  
# 790.9014
ed(v2,v3)  
# 61.26989  --> imply v2, v3 are "closer"
ed(v1,v3)  
# 761.4782  --> imply v1, v3 are "far apart"
```

As you can see, `v1, v2` and `v1, v3` have similar magnitude of distances in Euclidean case, but for arccosine, they are different (66.8 vs. 8.06). Is there anything particular that is revealed by the angle distance but not the Euclidean distance? I think the **orientation** information is emphasized in the angle distance.

Comment: Your code explicitly takes the magnitudes out and you are asking not to, so why not just leave out the division and use the dot products? However, it's questionable that this would qualify as a "distance." That brings up a more fundamental issue: *why are you doing this?* In what kind of analysis will these distances be used and how do you intend to interpret them?

Comment: @whuber: thanks for your reply! The inclusion of the denominator as a normalizing factor is to use the arccos function. I am thinking of an alternative way to "additionally" account for the magnitude based on this pairwise angle dissimilarity measure. Yes, it is not a distance in the strict sense, but for my application it should be fine.

Comment: Without knowing your application it's not possible to provide objective advice about a distance. My first point--and this still puzzles me--is that if you want a measure that accounts for magnitude, then (obviously) you *don't* use an arccosine. If you simply did not do all the extraneous calculations needed to *eliminate* the effect of the magnitudes, you would stop at computing the dot products (such as `v1 %*% v2'). I'm mystified about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Indeed, @alittleboy, you are doing something strange. The dot product is the angle weighted by the product of the two magnitudes. Why don't use it? Or just the euclidean distance? These things are [related](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36158/3277). So what kind of distance you want, in the end?

Comment: @ttnphns: thanks for the comments and the post! I am wondering if in high dimensions, the Euclidean distance is still proportional to the angle between the two vectors? From that post, the 2-dimensional plot is intuitive, but in some applications, the Euclidean distance may not be the most appropriate one to use. That drives me to consider the angle measure, which might reflect more insights in high-dimensional cases...

Comment: @alittleboy, 1) the law of cosines is valid for euclidean space of any dimensionality. 2) Yes, euclidean distance is far not ubiquitous. Tons of different other distance measures exist. You might use even the angle measured in degrees or radians (which is arc distance) and multiply it by the magnitudes. You are free to tailor any measure which you think best suits your tasks.

Comment: Even in *infinitely many dimensions,* any two vectors determine a subspace of dimension at most $2$: therefore the (Euclidean) relationships that hold in two dimensions among pairs of vectors hold *entirely without any change at all* in any number of higher dimensions, too.

Comment: @whuber: thanks! please see the update in the post -- I compared with Euclidean distance using the example data, and I think they sometimes are telling different stories... correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: You are absolutely correct: the choice of distance matters and different choices can reveal different things, tell different stories. Thus, in general, we should seek to select a distance based on what the data mean, how they are measured, and what we wish to learn from them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a close relationship between Euclidean distance and Angular distance.
(see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Properties)

So if you want to take magnitude into account, you may actually be looking for Euclidean distance...

Let's look at squared Euclidean, for simplicity:
$$
\sum_i (a_i - b_i)^2 = \sum_i \left(a_i^2 - 2 a_i b_i + b_i\right)\\
= \sum_i a_i^2 + \sum_i b_i^2 - 2 \sum_i a_i b_i = ||A|| + ||B|| - 2 (A \cdot B)
$$

Now let's assume $||A||=||B||=1$, i.e. vectors standardized to unit length.
Then Euclidean distance is $\sqrt{2 - 2 (A\cdot B)}$!

In essence, **Cosine similarity is like (squared) Euclidean distance after *scaling* each vector to unit length**. I.e. if you have data that is very different in magnitude, but you do *not* want to take magnitude into account, then use cosine.

Note that angular similarity is scale invariant:
$$
\operatorname{CosSim}\left(\frac{A}{||A||}, \frac{B}{||B||}\right)
= \operatorname{CosSim}\left(A, B\right)
$$
And if I didn't screw up somewhere (please edit then!):
$$
\operatorname{Euclidean}\left(A,B\right)^2
= ||A||^2 + ||B||^2 - 2 ||A|| ||B|| \operatorname{CosSim}\left(A, B\right)
$$

([*Law of Cosines*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)).

Conversely, normalizing your data before using Euclidean yields:
$$
\operatorname{Euclidean}\left(\frac{A}{||A||}, \frac{B}{||B||}\right)^2
= 2\left[1 - \operatorname{CosSim}\left(A, B\right)\right]
$$
(Note that the right hand is a popular way of converting cosine similarity to a distance!)
And cosine similarity is monotone to squared Euclidean on the normalized vectors:
$$
\operatorname{CosSim}\left(A, B\right) = 
1-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Euclidean}\left(\frac{A}{||A||}, \frac{B}{||B||}\right)^2
$$

As per @whuber's comment: the formula
$$
\operatorname{acos}\left[\operatorname{CosSim}\left(A, B\right)\right]
$$
yields the geodetic distance on the surface of the unit sphere to get from the point $A/||A||$ to the point $B/||B||$. For obvious reasons, the $0$ vector yields undefined results.

Comment: @Anoy-Mousse: thanks! Please see my updates for some questions related to your solution :)

Comment: Well, if you turn that around, Angular distance is essentially equivalent to Euclidean distance, when you take magnitude *not* into account... It's Euclidean distance with built-in normalization to unit length vectors.

Comment: @Anony That's almost correct: the angular distance is the geodetic distance on the unit sphere. It is not a Euclidean distance.

Comment: "equivalent" is a broad term. There exists a formula to convert. ;-) I've been mostly using cosine *similarity* actually; not cosine distance, because there is more than one "angular distance".