# When to use dot-product as a similarity metric

Tags: linear-algebra, similarities

I'm trying to understand which similarity measure should be used in which situations.

- Roughly speaking, when should someone use the dot product to assess similarity between vectors?
- Roughly speaking, when should someone use the norm of the vector difference to assess similarity between vectors?
- What are the pros and cons of these approaches?

I'm not looking for a specific answer on which one I should use for a specific problem. I'm wondering more generally about when these approaches should be expected to work well.

Answer (score 4):

Euclidean distance (norm of difference) and dot predict are [proportional to each other](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/clustering/similarity/measuring-similarity), while they are [not equal, but roughly the same](http://searchivarius.org/blog/there-no-difference-between-cosine-similarity-and-euclidean-distance-when-it-comes-normalized).

> After normalizing $a$ and $b$ such that$\|a\| = 1$ and $\|b\| = 1$,
> these three measures are related as:
>
> Euclidean distance = $\| a - b \| = \sqrt{\| a \|^2 + \|b\|^2 - 2
>  a^Tb} =\sqrt{2 - 2 \cos(\theta_{ab})}$
>
> Dot product = $\|a\|\|b\| \cos(\theta_{ab}) = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot
>  \cos(\theta_{ab}) = \cos(\theta_{ab}) $
>
> Cosine = $\cos(\theta_{ab})$
>
> Thus, all three similarity measures are equivalent because they are
> proportional to $\cos(\theta_{ab})$.

This is [also discussed in here](https://skeptric.com/cosine-is-euclidean/) and in the [Vector space model: cosine similarity vs euclidean distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72978/vector-space-model-cosine-similarity-vs-euclidean-distance) thread and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Properties). There was even an empirical evaluation by [Qian et al (2004)](https://www.cse.msu.edu/%7Epramanik/research/papers/2003Papers/sac04.pdf) concluding that

> Through our theoretical analysis and experimental results, we conclude
> that EUD and CAD are similar when applied to high dimensional NN
> queries. For normalized data and clustered data, EUD and CAD becomes
> even more similar.

Both metrics are similar and there are no strong reasons to prefer one over another in general.