# Is triangle inequality fulfilled for these correlation-based distances?

Tags: correlation, clustering, distance, metric

For hierarchical clustering I often see the following two "metrics" (they aren't exactly speaking) for measuring the distance between two random variables $X$ and $Y$:
$\newcommand{\Cor}{\mathrm{Cor}}$
\begin{align}
d_1(X,Y) &= 1-|\Cor(X,Y)|,  \\
d_2(X,Y) &= 1-(\Cor(X,Y))^2
\end{align}
Does either one fulfill the triangle inequality? If so how should I prove it other than just doing a bruteforce calculation? If they aren't metrics, what is a simple counter example?

Comment: You might be interested in reviewing this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.3145.pdf.

Comment: I do not know why the two results are equal, how to prove it, looking forward to your reply > set.seed(0) > x <- runif(50) > y <- runif(50) > cor(rank(x),rank(y),method = 'pearson') [1] 0.03183673 > ranked.x <- scale(rank(x)) / sqrt(length(x) - 1) / 2 > ranked.y <- scale(rank(y)) / sqrt(length(y) - 1) / 2 > 1 - 2 *sum((ranked.x - ranked.y)^2) [1] 0.03183673

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Metric_space) on your $d_1$ would yield:
$\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}$
$\newcommand{\Cor}{\mathrm{Cor}}$
$\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}$

\begin{align*}
d_1(X,Z) &\leq d_1(X,Y) + d_1(Y,Z) \\
1 - |\Cor(X,Z)| &\leq 1 - |\Cor(X,Y)| + 1 - |\Cor(Y,Z)| \\
\implies |\Cor(X,Y)| + |\Cor(Y,Z)| &\leq 1 + |\Cor(X,Z)|
\end{align*}

This seems quite an easy inequality to defeat. We can make the right-hand side as small as possible (exactly one) by making $X$ and $Z$ independent. Then can we find a $Y$ for which the left-hand side exceeds one?

If $Y=X+Z$ and $X$ and $Z$ have identical variance, then $\Cor(X,Y) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \approx 0.707$ and similarly for $\Cor(Y,Z)$, so the left-hand side is well above one and the inequality is violated. Example of this violation in R, where $X$ and $Z$ are components of a multivariate normal:

```r
library(MASS)
set.seed(123)
d1 <- function(a,b) {1 - abs(cor(a,b))}

Sigma    <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1), nrow=2) # covariance matrix of X and Z
matrixXZ <- mvrnorm(n=1e3, mu=c(0,0), Sigma=Sigma, empirical=TRUE)
X <- matrixXZ[,1] # mean 0, variance 1
Z <- matrixXZ[,2] # mean 0, variance 1
cor(X,Z) # nearly zero
Y <- X + Z

d1(X,Y) 
# 0.2928932
d1(Y,Z)
# 0.2928932
d1(X,Z)
# 1
d1(X,Z) <= d1(X,Y) + d1(Y,Z)
# FALSE
```

Though note this construction doesn't work with your $d_2$:

```r
d2 <- function(a,b) {1 - cor(a,b)^2}
d2(X,Y) 
# 0.5
d2(Y,Z)
# 0.5
d2(X,Z)
# 1
d2(X,Z) <= d2(X,Y) + d2(Y,Z)
# TRUE
```

Rather than launch a theoretical attack on $d_2$, at this stage I just found it easier to play around with the covariance matrix `Sigma` in R until a nice counterexample popped out. Allowing $\Var(X)=2$, $\Var(Z)=1$ and $\Cov(X,Z)=1$ gives:

$$\Var(Y)=\Var(X+Y)=\Var(X)+\Var(Z)+2\Cov(X,Z)=2+1+2=5$$

We can also investigate the covariances:

$$\Cov(X,Y)=\Cov(X,X+Z)=\Cov(X,X)+\Cov(X,Z)=2+1=3$$
$$\Cov(Y,Z)=\Cov(X+Z,Z)=\Cov(X,Z)+\Cov(Z,Z)=1+1=2$$

The squared correlations are then:
$$\Cor(X,Z)^2 = \frac{\Cov(X,Z)^2}{\Var(X)\Var(Z)}=\frac{1^2}{2\times1}=0.5$$
$$\Cor(X,Y)^2 = \frac{\Cov(X,Y)^2}{\Var(X)\Var(Y)}=\frac{3^2}{2\times5}=0.9$$
$$\Cor(Y,Z)^2 = \frac{\Cov(Y,Z)^2}{\Var(Y)\Var(Z)}=\frac{2^2}{5\times1}=0.8$$

Then $d_2(X,Z)=0.5$ while $d_2(X,Y)=0.1$ and $d_2(Y,Z)=0.2$ so the triangle inequality is violated by a substantial margin.

```r
Sigma    <- matrix(c(2,1,1,1), nrow=2) # covariance matrix of X and Z
matrixXZ <- mvrnorm(n=1e3, mu=c(0,0), Sigma=Sigma, empirical=TRUE)
X <- matrixXZ[,1] # mean 0, variance 2
Z <- matrixXZ[,2] # mean 0, variance 1
cor(X,Z) # 0.707
Y  <- X + Z
d2 <- function(a,b) {1 - cor(a,b)^2}
d2(X,Y) 
# 0.1
d2(Y,Z)
# 0.2
d2(X,Z)
# 0.5
d2(X,Z) <= d2(X,Y) + d2(Y,Z)
# FALSE
```

Answer (score 5):

Let us have three vectors (it could be variables or individuals) $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. And we standardized each of them to z-scores (mean=0, variance=1).

$\newcommand{\Cor}{\mathrm{Cor}}$

Then according to [cosine theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36158/3277) ("law of cosines") *squared euclidean distance* between two standardized vectors (say, X and Y) is $d_{XY}^2 = 2(n-1)(1-\cos_{XY})$, where $\cos_{XY}$, the cosine similarity, [is](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22520/3277) Pearson $r_{XY}$ due to z-standardization of vectors. We may safely omit $2(n-1)$ constant multiplier from our consideration.

So, it comes that the distance expressed in the question as $d_1(X,Y)=1-|\Cor(X,Y)|$ would be the squared euclidean distance if the formula were not ignoring the sign of the correlation coefficient.

If the matrix of $|r|$s happens to be gramian (positive semidefinite) then square root of "d1" distance is euclidean distance, which is metric of course. With not large matrices of $|r|$ it is often a case or near a case when the distances are not far from well converging in euclidean space. Since metric is a wider class than euclidean, a given matrix of distances "sqrt(d1)" might expect to appear metric quite often.

As for "d1" per se, which is "like" *squared* euclidean distance, it is definitely non-metric. Even true squared euclidean distance is not metric: it violates sometimes the triangle inequality principle. [In cluster analysis, squared euclidean distance is used quite often; however, the majority of such cases imply actually building the analysis on nonsquared distance, the squared ones being just a convenient input for calculations.] To see it (about squared euclidean $d$), let's draw our three vectors.

[image]

The vectors are unit-length (because standardized). Cosines of the angles ($\alpha$, $\beta$, $\alpha+\beta$) are $r_{XY}$, $r_{XZ}$, $r_{YZ}$, respectively. These angles spread corresponding euclidean distances between the vectors: $d_{XY}$, $d_{XZ}$, $d_{YZ}$. For simplicity, the three vectors are all on the same plane (and so the angle between $X$ and $Z$ is the sum of the two other, $\alpha+\beta$). It is the position in which the violation of triangle inequality by the distances *squared* is most prominent.

For, as you can see with eyes, the green square area excels the sum of the two red squares: $d_{YZ}^2 > d_{XY}^2 + d_{XZ}^2$.

Therefore regarding

> $d_1(X,Y)=1-|\Cor(X,Y)|$

distance we can say it is not metric. Because even when all $r$s were originally positive the distance is the euclidean $d^2$ which itself isn't metric.

What is about the second distance?

> $d_2(X,Y)=1-(\Cor(X,Y))^2$

Since correlation $r$ in the case of standardized vectors is $\cos$, $1-r^2$ is $\sin^2$. (Indeed, $1-r^2$ is `SSerror/SStotal` of a linear regression, a quantity which is the squared correlation of the dependent variable with something *orthogonal* to the predictor.) In that case draw the sines of the vectors, and make them squared (because we are talking about the distance which is $\sin^2$):

[image]

Although it is not quite obvious visually, the green $\sin_{YZ}^2$ square is again larger than the sum of red areas $\sin_{XY}^2 + \sin_{XZ}^2$.

It could be proved. On a plane, $\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \sin\alpha \cos\beta + \cos\alpha \sin\beta$. Square both sides since we are interested in $\sin^2$.

\begin{align}
\sin^2(\alpha+\beta) &= \sin^2\alpha (1-\sin^2\beta) + (1-\sin^2\alpha) \sin^2\beta + 2 \sin\alpha \cos\beta \cos\alpha \sin\beta  \\
                     &= \sin^2\alpha + \sin^2\beta -2 [\sin^2\alpha \sin^2\beta] +2 [\sin\alpha \cos\alpha \sin\beta \cos\beta]
\end{align}

In the last expression, two important terms are shown bracketed. If the second of the two is (or can be) larger than the first one then $\sin^2(\alpha+\beta) > \sin^2\alpha + \sin^2\beta$, and the "d2" distance violates triangular inequality. And it is so on our picture where $\alpha$ is about 40 degrees and $\beta$ is about 30 degrees (term 1 is `.1033` and term 2 is `.2132`). "D2" isn't metric.

The square root of "d2" distance - the sine dissimilarity measure - is metric though (I believe). You can play with various $\alpha$ and $\beta$ angles on my circle to make sure. Whether "d2" will show to be metric in a non-collinear setting (i.e. three vectors not on a plane) too - I can't say at this time, albeit I tentatively suppose it will.

Answer (score 4):

See also this preprint that I wrote: http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.3145 . I still need to take time and properly submit it. The abstract:

> We investigate two classes of transformations of cosine similarity and
>   Pearson and Spearman correlations into metric distances, utilising the
>   simple tool of metric-preserving functions. The first class puts
>   anti-correlated objects maximally far apart. Previously known
>   transforms fall within this class. The second class collates
>   correlated and anti-correlated objects. An example of such a
>   transformation that yields a metric distance is the sine function when
>   applied to centered data.

The upshot for your question is that *d1*, *d2* are indeed not metrics and that the square root of *d2* is in fact a proper metric.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Simplest counter-example:

for $X=(0,0)$ the distance is not defined at all, whatever your $Y$ is.

Any constant series has standard deviation $\sigma=0$, and thus causes a division by zero in the definition of $Cor$...

At most it is a metric on a subset of the data space, not including any constant series.

Comment: Good point! I must mention this in the pre-print mentioned elsewhere.