# Distance vs Dissimilarity measure

Tags: distance, similarities

I am reading up on distance and dissimilarity measures for my class on natural language processing and could not understand this slide. Why does the dissimilarity measure not satisfy item 3 ? What would an example be ?

[image]

Comment: To me, it seems point 1 implies point 3. Not sure how you could have a metric that satisfies 1 and not 3.

Comment: These are the three axioms of metricity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)). #3 is the "triangular inequality" axiom.

Comment: A note on terminology. Some authors define "distances" as metric dissimilarities. Thence, there are metric dissimilarities (=distances) and nonmetric dissimilarities. Other authors equate "distances" and "dissimilarities" to be synonyms. Thence, for them there are metric and nonmetric dissimilarities (= distances)

Comment: Thanks guys. Do you know if there is a page online where I get to see which distance satisfies / does not satisfy the 3 inequalities ? Im trying to select one for my project. So far I have seen that the KL and chi square do not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

## First Question

> Why does the dissimilarity measure not satisfy item 3?

The answer is that this is just the **definition** of a dissimilarity.

If a matrix fulfills the first two properties, the matrix defines a dissimilarity measure.
If it **additionally** also fulfills property 3, the matrix defines a distance measure.

Thus, a distance measure is also always a dissimilarity, but not vice versa.

## Second Question

> What would an example be (of a dissimilarity that is not a distance)?

A counterexample is

\begin{bmatrix}0&0.5&0\\0.5&0&0.4\\0&0.4&0\end{bmatrix}

In this case, the distance *(distance does not mean distance measure in this case!)* between observation 1 and observation 2 is 0.5.
Between observation 2 and observation 3 the distance is 0.4.
Between observation 1 and observation 3 the distance is 0.

The first two axioms hold: -> dissimilarity measure

The third axiom, on the other hand, does not hold:

d(observation 1, observation 2) = 0.5 > 0 + 0.4 = d(observation 1, observation 3) + d(observation 3, observation 2)

### Note

Such a distance matrix could occur from a numerical dataset for example for the correlation dissimilarity measure. This measure is discussed better in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165194/using-correlation-as-distance-metric-for-hierarchical-clustering) post.