# Normalized Levenshtein distance and triangle inequality

Tags: cosine-similarity

One question regarding to the triangle inequality of normalized Levenshtein Distance. I use the well-known form `D(X,Y) = 1 - d(X,Y) / MAX(|X|,|Y|)` where `d(X,Y)` is Levenshtein Distance.

And I understand it violates the triangle inequality. But I would like to ask: Can I still use it as a distance metric and under which circumstances should I really care about the triangle inequality?

Plus, I also note the cosine distance also violates the triangle inequality ([Proving that cosine distance function defined by cosine similarity between two unit vectors does not satisfy triangle inequality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198080/proving-that-cosine-distance-function-defined-by-cosine-similarity-between-two-u)), but why it's also widely used as distance function?

Thank you!

Comment: In comments to that reference I noted that the *square root* of the cosine "distance" essentially is a distance function (at least locally).  Frequently, algorithms based on distances can quickly compute squared distances but do not actually need to compute the distances themselves.