# distance and correlations

Tags: correlation, metric

For two random variables $X_i$ and $X_j$, I define:
$d(X_i,X_j)$ = $\sqrt{2(1-\rho_{i,j})}$ where $\rho_{i,j}$ is the Pearson correlation coefficient.
I want to show that d is a pseudometric.

The four axioms can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)

The axioms of nonnegativity and of symmetry are trivial.
If I am not mistaken, the identity of indiscernibles does not hold because if $X_i = a X_j$, $ \ d(X_i, X_j) = 0$ but $X_i \ne X_j$, that is why I want to show that it is "only" a pseudometric.

My main question is about the triangle inequality. How can I check it holds? If $cor(X,Y) = a$, $cor(Y,Z) = b$ and $cor(X,Z) = c$, by positive semidefiniteness of the correlation matrix you can say that $b \in [ac-\sqrt{(1-a^2)(1-c^2)}, \ ac+\sqrt{(1-a^2)(1-c^2)}]$ (the determinant is positive).

I want to show that $\sqrt{2(1-a)}+\sqrt{2(1-b)} \geq \sqrt{2(1-c)}$

In the "worst" case, $b = ac+\sqrt{(1-a^2)(1-c^2)}$

I tried to study the functions:
a $\mapsto \sqrt{2(1-c)} - \sqrt{2(1-a)} - \sqrt{2(1-b)}$ with b replaced by its upper bound - and the same function of c - to show that they are always negative on $[-1,1]^2$ but it soon gets intractable. I could only check the result numerically. I imagine there are much better ways to solve the problem. Do you know any of those?

PS: I have found the thread [Is triangle inequality fulfilled for these correlation-based distances?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135171/is-triangle-inequality-fulfilled-for-these-correlation-based-distances) and the answer of ttnphns but I could not find a proof of the fact that if the correlation matrix is PSD then $d$ is Euclidean. Isn't it at odd with the identity of indiscernibles?

Comment: `a proof of the fact that...d is Euclidean`. But did you see there the link to [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36158/3277)? The distance is euclidean because Pearson correlation is the [cosine](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22520/3277) between centered vectors (variables), its formula is the formula of cosine similarity.

Comment: Yes I have seen the link. But is the fact that Pearson correlation obeys the law of cosines (because the covariance is indeed a scalar product) enough to claim that the distance is Euclidean? Also, a Euclidean distance is a metric but it seems to me that the distance I consider does not verify the axiom "d(x,y) = 0 iff x = y". If X is proportional to Y for instance, the distance is zero because X and Y are perfectly correlated.

Comment: What you say is correct, but I wonder why you still need a proof. 1) By the cosine theorem formula, the distance which is tied with the scalar product is euclidean (if vectors are considered in euclidean space). 2) r is cosine of the scalar product when the two variables are centered; also, if both variables are standardized to unit variance, then the cosine theorem becomes $d=\sqrt{2(1-r)}$. That distance is still euclidean because centering/scaling don't make the space spanned by the vectors non-euclidean. So this d is simply the euclidean d between the transformed, standardized variables.

Comment: ok, I would perfectly agree with you if I could find the result: " By the cosine theorem formula, the distance which is tied with the scalar product is Euclidean". I know that if the distance is Euclidean, then the cosine law holds but I'm not sure of the converse.

Comment: Both euclidean distance and scalar product are properties of euclidean space. The law of cosine establishes their relation. If you show that $\sum XY$ is a scalar product in euclidean space and you believe in the law of cosines then automatically follows that the d is euclidean.

Comment: I understand ! So in the end, proving that this distance is a Euclidean distance boils down to prove that covariance is a scalar product because we build d in such a way that the distance and the scalar product are tied by the cosine theorem. Also I think I solved my second problem with the axiom: up to a rescaling + centering, two perfectly correlated variables are identical.

Comment: I agree with you.