# how a cosine similarity measure can be made a distance measure

Tags: classification

I want to make  cosine similarity  a distance measure  for undersampling of fraud data , but the problem is if I get the zero values it will give 0/0, what can I do for this what can be the alternative similarity  measures that are also distance measures.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36158/3277. _Squared_ euclidean distance is `2(1-s)` where `s` is cosine similarity.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

$dist = 1 - sim$ where $sim$ denotes the cosine similarity.