# Convert Pearson correlation matrix into dissimilarity matrix

Tags: distance, pearson-r, similarities, multidimensional-scaling, euclidean

I would like to execute multidimensional scaling ([MDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling)) based on a matrix of Pearson correlation coefficients. The [sklearn.manifold.MDS](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.MDS.html) function takes a dissimilarity matrix as an input and I therefore need to convert my similarity matrix into a dissimilarity/distance matrix. What is the correct way of doing so?

According to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36152/converting-similarity-matrix-to-euclidean-distance-matrix/36158#36158) answer, a similarity matrix (S) can be converted to an euclidean distance matrix (d) via:

```
d = sqrt(2(1-S))
```

It also notes that on some occasions, the factor 2 can be omitted:

```
d = sqrt(1-S)
```

According to [this](http://ramet.elte.hu/~podani/3-Distance,%20similarity.pdf) paper (eq. 3.4) and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.02213.pdf) paper (eq. 3), the conversion should be done as follows:

```
d = 1-S
```

Which of those answers is correct, given that my similarity matrix has values between [-1,1] and the diagonal elements are 1 (it is symmetric)?