# Euclidian distance vs cosine similarity

Tags: distance, image-processing, pattern-recognition, cosine-similarity

Currently I'm working on facial recognition. If I use encoding/feature vectors of 2 images which method will prove more accuracy, L2 norm or cosine similarity and why?

I read *"ICA performs significantly better using cosines rather than Euclidean distance as the similarity measure, whereas PCA performs the same for both."*

Why is this true?
When those methods will fail?
And if other better approach is possible.

Comment: Cosine similarity converted by the [cosine rule](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36158/3277) into a distance is called chord distance which is a case of euclidean distance. Therefore, analysis based on cosine is most of the time equivalent to the analysis based on squared chord distance.

Comment: Actually I have heard that cosine similarity gives better results but I'm not clear with the reasons.

Comment: You should clearly express what is PCA or ICA performing on _a distance_ (rather than a dataset or a covariance matrix).

Comment: Do you mean what's their functionality in this case?If so ICA is for extracting independent basis and pca compresses the matix